# templated lambda return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I want to write a little bit of code that maps enums to specific members of a struct.

The trouble is the members of the struct have different types, if they didn't I've just used an `std::array` of references or pointers to do this.

So I thought to use a lambda instead since they now have template params

Here's something like what I have:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int x;
    double y;
};

enum class keys
{
    x,
    y,
};

void print(foo f)
{
    auto get = [&f]<keys K, typename T>(std::integral_constant<keys, K>) -> T&
    {
        switch(K)
        {
            case keys::x: return f.x;
            case keys::y: return f.y;
        }
    };
    std::cout << get(std::integral_constant<keys, keys::x>{}) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << get(std::integral_constant<keys, keys::y>{}) <<std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    foo m{1,2.0};
    print(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, in my real code, I cannot modify the `foo` struct, and the types are much more complex than `int` or `double`.

But this code gives me errors like:

```
<source>: In function 'void print(foo)':
<source>:26:21: error: no match for call to '(print(foo)::<lambda(std::integral_constant<keys, K>)>) (std::integral_constant<keys, keys::x>)'
   26 |     std::cout << get(std::integral_constant<keys, keys::x>{}) <<std::endl;
      |                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:16: note: candidate: 'template<keys K, class T> print(foo)::<lambda(std::integral_constant<keys, K>)>'
   18 |     auto get = [&f]<keys K, typename T>(std::integral_constant<keys, K>) -> T&
      |                ^
<source>:18:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:26:21: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
   26 |     std::cout << get(std::integral_constant<keys, keys::x>{}) <<std::endl;
      |                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:27:21: error: no match for call to '(print(foo)::<lambda(std::integral_constant<keys, K>)>) (std::integral_constant<keys, keys::y>)'
   27 |     std::cout << get(std::integral_constant<keys, keys::y>{}) <<std::endl;
      |                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:16: note: candidate: 'template<keys K, class T> print(foo)::<lambda(std::integral_constant<keys, K>)>'
   18 |     auto get = [&f]<keys K, typename T>(std::integral_constant<keys, K>) -> T&
      |                ^
<source>:18:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:27:21: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
   27 |     std::cout << get(std::integral_constant<keys, keys::y>{}) <<std::endl;
      |                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

How can I work around this? I'm a little confused how the compiler fails to be able to deduce `T&`. One way I could work around this is via specializations but I was not able to figure out how to specialize a lambda function for specific template params.

Comment: why are you using `std::integral_constant` rather than simply the enum value?

Comment: The compiler can't deduce a return type because you have one case that returns `int` and one that returns `double`. There is no compile-time `switch` that would let you choose one of them but you can use `if constexpr`.

Comment: typo `print(foo);` -> `print(m);`

Comment: Why introduce this `key` thing and repeat every member name three times? (once in `foo`, once in `key`, once in `get`). You can use `&foo::x` and `&foo::y` as keys instead. https://godbolt.org/z/f6j6Y4vvr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing anything to the lambda that lets the compiler deduce what `T` should be. As [@molbdnilo  mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76225020/templated-lambda-return-type/76225278#comment134421150_76225020), your `switch` is not evaluated until runtime, and it returns different types for each value of `K`, so the compiler can't use that to deduce `T` at compile-time.

Just use `auto` instead for the return type, and then use `if constexpr` to let the compiler evaluate the conditions at compile-time and remove unused code, thus letting `auto` to deduce the type of whichever `return` is actually used.

For example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int x;
    double y;
};

enum class keys
{
    x,
    y,
};

// see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553
// for why this is needed below...
template<keys K>
inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;

void print(const foo& f)
{
    auto get = [&f]<keys K>() -> auto&
    {
        if constexpr (K == keys::x)
            return f.x;
        else if constexpr (K == keys::y)
            return f.y;
        else
            static_assert(always_false_v<K>, "Invalid key");
    };
    std::cout << get.operator()<keys::x>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << get.operator()<keys::y>() << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    foo m{1,2.0};
    print(m);
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/qr_3FNuKI)

Alternatively, as [@n.m. suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76225020/templated-lambda-return-type/76225278#comment134421613_76225020), you can just get rid of the `keys` enum and use pointer-to-members instead, eg:

```
include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int x;
    double y;
};

void print(const foo& f)
{
    auto get = [&f](auto member) -> auto&
    {
        return f.*member;
    };
    std::cout << get(&foo::x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get(&foo::y) << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    foo m{1,2.0};
    print(m);
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/2mas3fd8Y)

Comment: Thank you for answering the question directly as well as providing an improvement suggestion, in the real code I ended up using a combination of the two. The reasoning I did this is because the enum names are fixed while multiple structures are present.

The pointer to member strategy suggested solves the multiple structure problem as well because I can simply pass in their pointer to members <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class template for the mapping:

```
template <keys> struct key_to_foo_mem;
template <> struct key_to_foo_mem<keys::x> { auto& operator()(const foo& f){ return f.x; } };
template <> struct key_to_foo_mem<keys::y> { auto& operator()(const foo& f){ return f.y; } };

void print(foo f)
{
    std::cout << key_to_foo_mem<keys::x>()(f) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << key_to_foo_mem<keys::y>()(f) <<std::endl;
}
```

Your lambda approach has two issues: `T` is used but neither provided explicitly nor deduced. The return type is deduced inconsistently from the two cases, but a function can have only one return type. Moreover you use a trailing return of `T&` which does surpress the deduction of the return type by the compiler.

You can remove `T` and use `constexpr if` :

```
void print(foo f)
{
    auto get = [&f]<keys K>(std::integral_constant<keys, K>)
    {
        if constexpr(K == keys::x) { return f.x; }
        else { return f.x; }
    };
    std::cout << get(std::integral_constant<keys, keys::x>{}) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << get(std::integral_constant<keys, keys::y>{}) <<std::endl;
}
```

---

> I'm a little confused how the compiler fails to be able to deduce
> T&.

When you use trailing return type you are telling the compiler "this is the type" (ie you surpress the deduction) but `-> T&` as trailing return type makes no sense. Once you use `constexpr if` the compiler can deduce the return type itself (lambdas have implicit `auto` return type).

> One way I could work around this is via specializations but I was not able to figure out how to specialize a lambda function for specific template param

Its important to understand that for the above lambda expression it is the `operator()` that is templated, not the type of the lambda. How you can use specialization I have shown above (though it is specialization of a class template, not of a member template).